# Change color temperature throughout the day

Tags: f.lux

Is it possible to have f.lux change the color temperature continuously throughout the day, rather than over the course of 30 seconds or whatever at sunset? Seems weird to have it almost be a square wave like that. I am used to using redshift in Linux, which changes continuously throughout the day. Any way to get f.lux to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### I am used to using redshift in Linux, which changes continuously throughout the day.

> Any way to get f.lux to do that?

From the f.lux FAQ:

> This changes too fast, it always shocks me.
>
> The f.lux transition can be CPU intensive, so f.lux tries to be polite about it. To make it slow, you can use the special 1-hour slow transition option under settings instead.

Source [f.lux support](https://justgetflux.com/faq.html)

The best you can do is to get it to change over a 60 minute timescale:

- Right click f.lux icon (in the system tray) and select "Settings"
- Set the "Transition Speed" to "Slow (60m).

  [image]